# oauth V2 token is giving invalid scope

Tags: rest, uber-api

API Curl:

```
curl --location 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token' \
\--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
\--data-urlencode 'client_secret=SECRET_FROM_APPLICATIONS_DASHBOARD' \
\--data-urlencode 'client_id=CLIENTID_FROM_APPLICATIONS_DASHBOARD' \
\--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
\--data-urlencode 'scopes=guests.trips'
```

Documentation Link : https://developer.uber.com/docs/guest-rides/guides/authentication

I am expecting it to give :

```
{
    "access_token": "{TokenValue}",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 2592000,
    "scope": "guests.trips"
}
```

but I am getting this as output in postman :

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "scope(s) are invalid"
}
```

I am not making any other API call other than mentioned above. Do I need to do anything prior to calling this endpoint if not then why invalid scopes is coming as output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the scope request parameter has a syntax error.
It should be 'scope' and not 'scopes'.
This is also why you get the error_code 'invalid_scope', likely because it is unknown as of [OAuth Spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.2.2.1).

You can have a look at ubers own [API documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v2/token-post),
where they have an excellent example of client_credentials as well.